# Custom menu on Google Forms not showing up

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

It is as simple as the title. Here is my code, written on a bound to file script:

```js
function onOpen(e){
  var ui = FormApp.getUi();
  ui
  .createMenu("Atualizar perguntas")
  .addItem("Atualizar todas", "updateAllQuestions")
  .addToUi()
}
```

The function `updateAllQuestions` works on its own. I even added the `onOpen`function to a trigger in the Project Triggers UI, for no good. Doing the same things works finely with Spreadsheets, but not with FormApps.

For the record, I'm trying to expose that menu to the editors of the forms, not to the  users (which I know to be impossible, as of now, AFAIK).

TO be quite honest, I cannot even figure where is a custom menu supposed to show up - unlike Spreadsheets, which have a clear menu bar area, forms UI is somewhat different, with buttons instead of Menu bars, so I'm quite confused.

Any ideas on this?

EDIT: making some more tests, I realize I simply cannot access the UI on the forms. I cannot generate alerts, custom messages, anything - it is like the Forms UI is somehow broken.

Comment: You mean it shows in the form editor, and not on the form responder view, right? Or you actually meant the menu will show up on the Apps Script view (the one with my code, and such)?

I don't understand. For me, nothing related to the UI seems to be working. Could you share a sample form with me, so I can compare and see what is going on?

Comment: I used your code exactly as it written in your example and I rewrote my comment.

Comment: I understand that, but, even creating a new form from another account, I cannot get it to work. Can you share at least a print of the screen with the newly created menu? Not even `FormApp.getUi().alert("test");` will work for me, no matter how or where I run it.

Comment: Nevermind - it shows up unders the Add-ons menu. I couldn't find that information anywhere, hence the confusion. Thank you for your time!
(although, indeed, calling `alert` from Apps Script would not work anyway, I don't know why)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just copied the code and pasted it into the script editor and run and authorized it. And then looked by on the edit form and it was there.

[image]

Comment: Thank you!
Just for the records, how did you record that gif? I alway wanated to post a cool step-by-step gif like this, and never knew how.

Comment: I have a program called Camtasia Studio. It's really easy to use to create videos from your computer screen.